# New use account confirmation email change?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email-templates

if the new user register in magento(1.9), the account confirmation email will be sent to the registered e-mail.

in that i like to remove the password  text. can you please any one give idea for that 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is located in `app/locale/[language]/email/templates/account_new.html` (or any of the other `account_` emails you might want to change)

Here you can search for the word "Password" and replace that line